# How to auto run python Selenium script on an ubuntu server in the backgroud

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu

**What I need**

I have a Python Selenium script. When I run it on my local Ubuntu PC - it works fine
But when I uploaded it to a server I face a problem. The server has no display
I solved this problem with X Virtual Framebuffer display. What I need - is to automatically setup the display and run my script in the background

**Problem**

Now I run it manually the following way

1. I go to the terminal
2. Set the display with the following commands

   export DISPLAY=:1

   Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen $DISPLAY 1280x1024x16 &
3. Run the python script with command python3 products2.py

This works fine.

But I need it to run automatically in the background
I created a conf file for supervisor and run the python script with supervisor.

```
[program:prod]
command = /root/lowescom/l-env/bin/python3.10 /root/lowescom/lowes_project/modules/products2.py
user = root
autorestart = true
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /root/lowescom/lowes_project/logs/debug.log
```

But this don't work. Even if I set up the display manually - it doesn't work

**Question**

How can I run my python Selenium script in the background automatically. The display setup should also be automated.

**Update**

I have just tried to use no-sandbox. But still not working

```
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: have tried using `subprocess`?

Comment: have you tried chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using chromedriver you should set the option:

`chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')`

for firefox you can check the pyvirtualdisplay module.

Comment: I use undetected_chromedriver. I've updated my question. I added no sandbox. Please look
But it still now working